# Download Ubuntu 12.04 through Vuze?

Tags: upgrade, downloads, bittorrent

I have Ubuntu 11.04 installed on my system. Now as Ubuntu 12.04 is released I want to download the latter through Vuze.

So how to download the Ubuntu 12.04 disk image in Vuze?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ and copy the URL of the
   torrent file you want to download to your clipboard.
2. Open Vuze. Click 'File' -> 'Open' -> 'Torren File...' or press
   shortcut CTRL+O. Click 'Add URL'. In the new window the URL field will
   automatically be filled with the URL from the clipboard.
3. Check preferences like download destination and when to start the
   download (add mode) and confirm with Ok. Download will either be
   queued or start immediately.

[image: Vuze's 'Open Torrents(s)' dialog]

Alternatively you can navigate through the ubuntu.com website. Currently it's 'Downloads' -> 'Alternative options' -> 'Take a look at a full list of our previous versions and alternative downloads' -> 'BitTorrent'.

Answer (score 2):

You can find torrent files at http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/